# WPF application correct usage of interface and common class

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application i have three executable.

On each executable , there is a Mainwindow.xaml & Mainwindow.xaml.cs, each of this implements the common Interface IMainwindow which is residing in a common project.
So there main window controls are quite different, the namespaces is obviously different.

How can i make the partial common Mainwindow.xaml  class that can be used with this three application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make partial classes the namespaces have to be identical. What you can make is a base class, but not for the view (xaml), it already inherited from UserControl and multiple inheritance is not supported in C#.

A possible option would be to wrap a common view into the three MainWindow.xaml, e.g with a ContentControl. Basicly you create a UserControl and reuse it every time.

But honestly I don't understand why do you have 3 executable in the same solution. Looks like you try to develop a common framework, but in this case the main windows still gonna be different.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution for my issue. There is a posibility to derive a base class and we can define a window from the base class in wpf 
Please go through the below [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/11/02/creating-a-base-window-class-in-wpf.aspx)

Thanks for your support